# Hibernate generates query without using where cluase

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I use hibernate and MySQL.
I have a query in MySQL database which looks like:

```
select
  phones0_.c_id as c_id_1, phones0_.cp_id as cp_id1_2, phones0_.cp_phone as cp_phon1
from
  customer_phone phones0
where
  phones0_.c_id in (select customer0_.c_id from customer customer0_ )
```

The issue is that there is no where clause in nested select. But I always use restrictions when i do some operations in JpaRepository.
I guess there are some issues in mapping.

Here are the examples of entities:

```
@Data
@Entity
class Customer {
  @GeneratedValue
  @Id
  @Column(name="c_id")
  Long id;

  @Column(name="c_name")
  private String name;

  @OneToMany( mappedBy = "customer" )
  @Fetch( FetchMode.SUBSELECT )
  private List<CustomerPhone> phones;
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_phone")
class CustomerPhone {
  @GeneratedValue
  @Id
  @Column(name="cp_id")
  Long id;

  @Column(name="cp_phone")
  private String phone;

  @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
  @JoinColumn( name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false )
  private Customer customer;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the hql query that you execute.

Comment: I'm trying to guess what causes this kind of query logged via MySQL slow_log.
Because nested query should be kind of a 'select c_id from customer where c_id = ?' But where clause is absent.

Comment: When I set option show_sql to true i cannot find any similar query.
I can see this query only in MySQL slow log

Comment: Please enable `hibernate.use_sql_comments`. It will allow you to find out what hql query lead to the above sql,